# C++, are the loop control variable and this variable within the loop the same?

Tags: c++

In this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<key; i++){
        int counter=((len)/div);
}
```

Is the loop control variable `int i` the same as `int counter`? If not, why was `int counter` able to be used without being initialized prior to the loop?

Full function code below.

```
void splitEncoded(string strarray[], int key, string msg){
    int cycle= (2 * key)-2;
    int div=cycle;
    int len=msg.length();
    int remainder=0;
    int pos=0;
    for(int i=0; i<key; i++){
        int counter=((len)/div);

        if(cycle!=0 && remainder!=0){
            counter= 2*counter;
            if((len%div)>=(div-(i-1))){
                counter+=2;
            } 

            else if((len%div)>i){
                counter++;
            }
        }  

        else if(((len)%div)>i){
            counter++;
        }

        strarray[i]=msg.substr(pos,counter);
        pos+=counter;
        cycle=cycle-2;
        remainder+=2;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you identify the exact spot you believe where `int counter` "was used without being initialized prior to the loop"?

Comment: Who told you all variables have to be initialized prior to the loop and you can't create new variables inside loops?

Comment: I am confused about which variable is controlling the number of times the loop executes. It seems to be int counter, but in all previous code I've worked with, int i was the loop control variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the loop control variable "int i" the same as "int counter"?

Er, no, the variables are not the same. They have different names...

> If not, why was "int counter" able to be used without being initialized prior to the loop?

Because it was initialized inside the loop.

```
int counter=((len)/div);
```

The line above creates a *new* variable called `counter` in each iteration of the loop initialized with the result of the operation `((len)/div)`.

Comment: Which one is the counter then? Typically the loop control variable (int i) would be the counter that determines the number of cycles of the loop, I thought?

Comment: Just because it's called `counter` doesn't mean it's the loop counter. Whatever variable is incremented and compared in the `for` statement is the one that controls the loop. `counter` is independent in this case, it's just a value computed at every loop iteration.

Comment: @Hannah Hard to say. Both `counter` and `i` are incremented, so you could say they are both counters.